# How to rename a color within a color scheme in PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010, color-theme

Is it possible to rename the colors of a color scheme in PowerPoint 2010?

I have this client that wants different names on the colors, not Accent 1, Accent 2, etc.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: For future readers: He's not asking how to rename a color scheme as his title says. (This could be done by modifying the corresponding XML under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 15\Theme Colors`.) He's asking if it's possible to rename internal names for different sections of a scheme.

Comment: @nixda I've edited the question, I think is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

In PP 2010 you can use ColorSwatch (http://skp.mvps.org/swatch.htm) to rename Colors.
The link is to a addon with easy How to use instructions, How to use install instructions and a video if you need more help

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue, anyone that has a solution?

I tried this but don't know if it solves the issue: https://www.empowersuite.com/en/blog/your-own-colors-in-powerpoint-master-color-theme-and-custom-colors

Comment: You can't rename the theme colors as requested; the link you pointed to and the one at skp.mvps.org describe methods for adding new Custom colors, the ones that appear below the them colors in the color picker. Those can be given any name you like.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145699)